# What is relativepagescore meta tag and what is its importance in SEO?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

What is the use of `relativepagescore` meta tag and how does it effect SEO?

```
<meta name="relativepagescore" content="555">
```

Comment: Google turns up nothing. The only thing I can think of is that it is being used like page weight to indicate which pages (relatively speaking) are more important on a site. But I really don't know.

Comment: Where did you find information about this tag? We need reference. Looks like you pulled it from another StackOverflow question, which may have used the tag as a pseudo example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about SEO are off-topic. SEO questions may be asked on Webmasters.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive research I found the source of the tag, his associated to [OpenSearch xml file](http://www.opensearch.org/Home).

This meta tag points to the internal rating of the page.

**There is no evidence that the search engines even know\read relativepagescore meta tag, and therefore there is no affect on the relevance of Google search engines results.**

But if your site has an internal search engine i will recommend you to consider the use of OpenSearch project.

Which influence directly on your site traffic, build a loyal users, and influence you website SEO work

Explanation of the installation and use of the file you will find [here](http://www.opensearch.org/Community/OpenSearch_search_clients)